# Ansible: Dynamically copy files/directories depending on hostname

Tags: ansible-2.x

I want to dynamically map IPs to directories in order to divide the work of copying and processing lists of repositories on remote hosts.

Goal is to have the following:

```
app/_data/repo-list-0 copies to 10.0.0.1
app/_data/repo-list-1 copies to 10.0.0.2
app/_data/repo-list-2 copies to 10.0.0.3

etc..
```

```
# ansible/hosts
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3

etc..
```

my source structure is like so where each directory contains ~10 json files

```
app/_data/repo-list-0/repo-list-[1-10].json
app/_data/repo-list-1/repo-list-[2-20].json
app/_data/repo-list-2/repo-list-[3-30].json

etc..
```

Copy Data Task

```
# ansible/playbooks/copy_data.yml
---
  - name: Copy Data
    hosts: all
    user: ec2-user
    vars:
      app: ...
    tasks:
     - name: copy repo-range to hosts
       copy:
         src: "app/_data/repo-list-0"
         dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/{{ app }}/_data"
       when: inventory_hostname == "10.0.0.1"
     - name: copy repo-range to hosts
       copy:
         src: "app/_data/repo-list-1"
         dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/{{ app }}/_data"
       when: inventory_hostname == "10.0.0.2"
     - name: copy repo-range to hosts
       copy:
         src: "app/_data/repo-list-2"
         dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/{{ app }}/_data"
       when: inventory_hostname == "10.0.0.3"

etc..
```

The reason for dynamically copying contents is because when the full application is run, new instances are deployed in AWS and I have to manually change each IP.

I tried to create a global variable and increment the source on when the host changes.

Answer (score 0):

The follow sets the index of the current target-host as part of the src directory and gets the current IP address.

```
- name: copy repo-range to hosts
          copy:
            src: "../../_data/repo-list-{{ play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) }}"
            dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/{{ app }}/_data"
          when: inventory_hostname == hostvars[inventory_hostname]['inventory_hostname']
```

Results in:

```
10.0.0.1/ec2-user/app/_data/repo-list-0
10.0.0.2/ec2-user/app/_data/repo-list-1
10.0.0.3/ec2-user/app/_data/repo-list-2
```